# Why am I not getting an email address from .SenderEmailAddress?

Tags: vba, ms-word, outlook

I am trying to create a macro in a Word form where it saves the form as a PDF, attaches it to an email, then sends the email to a predefined email address while CCing the submitter so they have a copy of the form.

I have everything working except I cannot for the life of me figure out how to get it to grab the sender email address.

Here is the macro:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim OL              As Object
Dim EmailItem       As Object

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
SubmitEmail = EmailItem.SenderEmailAddress


ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="\\folder\folder\file.pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF


With EmailItem
    .Subject = "Completed Training Selection Form"
    .Body = "See Attached"
    .To = "submit@test.com"
    .CC = SubmitEmail
    .Attachments.Add "\\folder\folder\file.pdf"
    .Send
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Form submitted. Check your email for a copy of the form."

Set OL = Nothing
Set EmailItem = Nothing

End Sub
```

The macro works but it does not CC anyone. I've tried so many different ways to grab the sender address from moving the code around to stepping all the way back to the account object.

I've added SubmitEmail to the body message to confirm it is blank. Is there something more I need to do since it is a Word macro and EmailItem is an Outlook object? Could computer/network permissions affect it? The email sends just fine from the sender's account but I am at a total loss right now.

**Edit:** I've even done .CC = .SenderEmailAddress and still nothing.

Comment: Yeah, it's supposed to be the submitter's email address. So the auto email CC's the sender. I've tried variables, I've tried .CC = .SenderEmailAddress, but it's always blank. It will compile but any variable or output I try to but the sender's address in comes up blank.

Comment: Try using `Option Explicit` on  your code. and see if its throwing Errors

Comment: Use the `Recipients` collection to add your `TO` and `CC` recipients, and finally perform a `Recipients.ResolveAll` as explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff184598.aspx). `SenderEmailAddress` is only set for received mails, not for freshly created new `MailItem` objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding the sender email address of the message that you just created, of course SenderEmailAddress will be "" since the message has never been submitted.

Is it supposed to be the address of the current user? Try `Application.Session.CurrentUser.Address`.